# #states doesn't work with Profile2

Tags: drupal-7

I have checkbox created by Profile2 called field_apply. Then i use hook_form_alter to add a texfield which should be visible when checkbox is checked.

```
function test_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['profile_test']['test'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Test text',
      '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
          ':input[name="field_apply"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But #states doesn't work. Textfield is still visible even if field_apply is not checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it :)** 
Name of the field in #state was wrong.
Just use firebug, select field_apply checkbox, copy value of "name" attribute and replace "field_apply" in  ':input[name="field_apply"]'... So in the example above #states attribute should look like this:

```
'visible' => array(':input[name="profile_test[field_apply][und]"]' => array('checked' => TRUE)),
```